# Segue causes breakpoint when clicking the cell to Detail view

Tags: objective-c, segue

The Cell which is in a collection view causes a breakpoint when clicked to show the larger image in a detail view. The cells display the images as they should but the detail view isn't displaying the image. If you need any more info form my part, let me know. The Clues provided are. `(lldb)`

```
    {
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class])); [BREAKPOINT]
    }
}                                                                                                                                                                                                       The code that generates the cell information and passes through the segue.                           

    - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    // code for the custom cell created:


    Cell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kCellID_Biffy forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // load  image
    NSString *imageToLoad_Biffy = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d_Biffy.jpg", indexPath.row];
    cell.image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageToLoad_Biffy];



    return cell;
}


- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail_biffy"])
    {
        NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [[self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems] objectAtIndex:0];

        // loads the image 

        NSString *imageNameToLoad = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d_Biffy", selectedIndexPath.row];
        NSString *pathToImage = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:imageNameToLoad ofType:@"jpg"];
        UIImage *image2 = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:pathToImage];
;

        Detail_ViewController_Biffy *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
       detailViewController.image2 = image2;

    }
}     NEW CODE:  

@interface Detail_ViewController_Biffy ()


@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *images;


@end

@implementation Detail_ViewController_Biffy

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.images.image = self.image2;  <------yellow sign Incompatible pointer types assigning to UIImage from Ui IMageview


}

@end
```

Comment: That's not where the error is happening.  Provide us with the code you have for clicking a cell.  Also if a backtrace was generated (hint, it probably was) since that will tell you almost exactly where the exception occurred.

Comment: The only break point occuring is within the app delegate. When there's two sets of collection views deriving from one tab bar does there need to be two app delegates or just the one? (Just thought of this..)

Comment: What is the debugger spewing out?   There's something you aren't posting here that will tell us almost exactly what your problem is.  And no, never use more than one app delegate.

Comment: The debugger litterally displays (lldb) which is why I'm puzzled.

Comment: BUT! under the app delegate it displays this: (<Detail_ViewController_Biffy 0x7594e60> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key image.') but the view controller and detail view controller both have new classes applied to them. so shouldn't be a prob, but obv is..

Comment: Type in `bt` in the debugger window.  That should give you the backtrace.

Comment: I've added new code which displays a yellow warning sign which I didn't notice before.. I've edited the code into the original question

Comment: Is `self.image2` an UIImageView ? Try `self.image2.image` to suppress the warning.

Comment: no longer crashing, but the file doesn't load either. Who would you resolve the warnging?

Comment: no worries, solved thanks both for your time :)

Comment: Glad you solved it. so finally what was the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You said the error is :
`( setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key image.')`

Assuming you use storyboards, I think you did one of those following things:

Modified connection to your IBOutlets (certainly you image)

Renamed one property

Deleted one property from your code without deleting the connection in the storyboard

The class specified to one of your view controller isn't the same you use in your code

Double-check the consistency between your storyboard and your code ! I hope it helps!